# Separable and normal

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\mathbb{N}$ and $\tau = \mathbb{N} ∪ \{∅ \} ∪ \{ A_n : n= 1,2,3,\ldots \}$ where $A_n=\{1,2,3,..., n\}$, then show that $(X, \tau)$ is separable .

I know that if $X$ is a countable set, then $(X, \tau)$ is separable for any topology because $\overline{X} =X$ which is countable dense.

Comment: What is your definition of normal? Do you mean $T_4 + T_1$? or just $T_4$?

Comment: @G.Chiusole: For many of us $T_4$ is *normal* + $T_1$, so that the $T_i$ properties form a genuine hierarchy, exactly as their names suggest. Here the OP clearly means what I call normal, which does not imply $T_1$.

Comment: Im modified the question
He wants show that separable just this.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that every pair of nonempty closed sets has a nonempty intersection.

Comment: Im modified the question
He wants show that separable just.

Comment: @eslamababneh I do not understand you. In the paragraph where you say "I know that if $X$ is countable..." you already gives a proof of separability.

Comment: Is N countable ??

Comment: @eslamababneh yes. By definition, a set X is countable if there exists an injection from X to N.

Comment: Ok thank you. Is (1,3) connected